# Tag analyzer snippet

Tags: discussion, tags

I coded basic tag analyzer that pulls tags and their counts from API and compiles a list.

If anyone wants to improve my code or help with tag organizations (actively or by pointing out tags that need attention, whatever your rep is :) - feel free to. This is going slowly as my time and mood allow...

https://gist.github.com/926100

Answer (score 3):

**These combinations could be merged / unified or need some diamond attention imho:**

<strike>`<menu>`</strike> / `<menus>`
<strike>`<custom>`</strike> / `<customization>` / <strike>`<customize>`</strike>
`<debug>` / <strike>`<debugging>`</strike>
<strike>`<custom-post-type>`</strike> / `<custom-post-types>`
<strike>`<error>`</strike> / `<errors>`
<strike>`<function>`</strike> / `<functions>`
`<memory>` / <strike>`<memory-issues>`</strike>
<strike>`<license>`</strike> / `<licensing>`
<strike>`<upload>`</strike> / `<uploads>`

`<url-rewriting>` / `<rewrite-rules>` not sure, left alone for now.
`<wordpres 3.x.x>` / `<version-x>`  don't start me on this...
`<i18n>` / `<multi-language>` / `<translation>`   tricky nuances, left alone for now
`<loading-time>` / `<performance>`  different things
`<apply-filters>` / `<add-filter>` / `<filters>` different things
`<front-page>` / `<home-page>`  different things
`<domain>` / `<domain-mapping>`  different things

Just the first impression. Nice little script anyway. And educative for me too.
*(getting data from SE API looks much easier then I have expected)*

Comment: Nice list! You can follow the status at the [tag synonym page](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms), but maybe only if you have enough rep?

Comment: I'd argue that `<domain>` and `<domain-mapping>` are two different topics ... the same with `<front-page>` and `<home-page>` ... but the rest looks good to me.

Comment: Did a batch, will get to the rest later...

Comment: I tried to create a synonym `<wordpress-3.0>` to `<version-3.0>` but I did it backwards.  Is there anyway to delete my suggestion or just wait till it gets voted down?

Comment: @Chris_O deleted, I am waiting on that mess until we get final say form higher powers if we can get `wordpress-x` banned.